# Error in seq.default when trying to use a function after grouping per day

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some values per time.

```
library(flux)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydf <- tibble(mydate = as.Date(c("2019-05-11 23:55:00", "2019-05-11 23:56:00", "2019-05-11 23:57:00", "2019-05-11 23:58:00",
                                  "2019-05-12 23:55:00", "2019-05-12 23:56:00", "2019-05-12 23:57:00", "2019-05-12 23:58:00")),
               myval = c(101.23, 102.34, 105.43, 106.7, 107.1, 108.2, 109.2, 110.1))
```

I want to find auc per day. So, I am trying:

```
mydf <- mydf %>%
    group_by(day = floor_date(mydate, "day")) %>%
    summarise(Valmean = mean(myval, na.rm = TRUE),
              perDayIntegr = auc(time(day), Valmean))
```

and I am receiving:

```
Error in seq.default(x[1], x[2], length.out = dens) : 
  'to' must be a finite number
```

UPDATE:

If I use this dataset:

```
mydf <- tibble(mydate = as.Date(c("2019-05-11 23:55:00", "2019-05-11 23:56:00", "2019-05-11 23:57:00", "2019-05-11 23:58:00",
                                  "2019-05-12 23:55:00", "2019-05-12 23:56:00", "2019-05-12 23:57:00", "2019-05-12 23:58:00",
                                  "2019-05-13 23:55:00", "2019-05-13 23:56:00", "2019-05-13 23:57:00", "2019-05-14 23:58:00")),
               myval = c(101.23, 102.34, 105.43, 106.7, 107.1, 108.2, 109.2, 110.1, 111, 112, 113, 114))
```

where in the last line I am using only one row for date `"2019-05-14 23:58:00"`
it still gives me the error.

Comment: Does your real data have any groups with all NA for `myval`? That would make `Valmean` NaN, and when you give NaN as the second argument of `seq`, you get that error.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan:Sorry, I didn't get the comment since for the data I am posting there are no NA values and still I get the error.

Comment: @George In the example documentation, the same length is passed as second parameter, also, as `ts` object

Comment: @George my mistake. Looks like you need the second argument to be the same length as the first, as akrun says. You can use `rep` to do so i.e. `auc(time(day), rep(Valmean, n()))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan:Ok, this works for this example.Using it with real data (where no NA values exist) it shows again the same error..

Comment: Please check whether it is only for a subset of groups, in that case, you can narrow it down to understand the issue

Comment: @akrun:I have updated my post.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan:I have updated my post

Comment: If there is only 1 point the area under curve should be 0 right? If that's correct, you could do something like `if(n() == 1) 0 else auc(time(day), rep(Valmean, n()))`

Comment: Actually, after realizing what you're trying to do here, you could just do `Valmean*(diff(range(time(day))))` instead and forget about `auc` and all the `rep` and `if` stuff. The results are the same as that of my `if`statement above. (for the example data, at least. I think it should be the same generally too though). If y is constant, the auc/integral is just the area of the rectangle length*width.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan:Yup!You are right! Thanks! (Make it an answer please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems

1. The `y` in `auc` needs to be the same length as `x`
2. The `auc` function apparently wasn't written to handle the case of length-1 input vectors.

For (1) we can use `rep` to get the lengths to match, and for (2) we know the auc for a single point should be 0, so we can write an `if` for that.

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(day = floor_date(mydate, "day")) %>%
    summarise(Valmean = mean(myval, na.rm = TRUE),
              perDayIntegr = if(n() == 1) 0 else auc(time(day), rep(Valmean, n())))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   day        Valmean perDayIntegr
#   <date>       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 2019-05-11    104.         312.
# 2 2019-05-12    109.         326.
# 3 2019-05-13    112          224.
# 4 2019-05-14    114            0
```

Actually, the auc with y equal to the mean should always be the same as the regular auc, so you could also do this instead to avoid the `rep`.

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(day = floor_date(mydate, "day")) %>%
    summarise(Valmean = mean(myval, na.rm = TRUE),
              perDayIntegr = if(n() == 1) 0 else auc(time(day), myval))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   day        Valmean perDayIntegr
#   <date>       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 2019-05-11    104.         312.
# 2 2019-05-12    109.         326.
# 3 2019-05-13    112          224.
# 4 2019-05-14    114            0
```

However, since you already have the mean `Valmean`, we can calculate the mean explicitly as `Valmean`*(delta x) rather than using `auc` to employ the trapezoid rule.

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(day = floor_date(mydate, "day")) %>%
    summarise(Valmean = mean(myval, na.rm = TRUE),
              perDayIntegr = Valmean*(diff(range(time(day)))))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   day        Valmean perDayIntegr
#   <date>       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 2019-05-11    104.         312.
# 2 2019-05-12    109.         326.
# 3 2019-05-13    112          224.
# 4 2019-05-14    114            0
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because `Valmean`, as a summary value, is a vector of length 1 in the call to `auc`, whereas `auc` needs at least two points `(x, y)`. Should the length-one vector come from `NA` values or from a `day` group for which the data has only one record, you'll get the error.

I'm not sure to understand if you need one auc for each day, or the auc from the curve defined by the couples `(day, Valmean)`. For the first case, you need to follow @IceCreamToucan's answer

In the other case, simply compute the auc after grouping by :

```
mydf <- mydf %>%
    group_by(day = floor_date(mydate, "day")) %>%
    summarise(
        Valmean = mean(myval, na.rm = TRUE),
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    summarise(
        perDayIntegr = auc(time(day), Valmean)
    )

>  perDayIntegr
>         <dbl>
>  1         330.
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error.. As far as I understand the error exists when I have for example only 1 row with a certain date (note that I don't have any na). For example, I have dates `2018-01-01, 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 2018-01-02` etc.This runs ok. But if I have `2018-01-01, 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 2018-01-03 2018-01-03`, then the error appears! ( there is only one row for 2018-01-02)

Comment: Updated my answer after @IceCreamToucan's